# Sorbet cannot resolve constant even though it is defined

Tags: ruby, sorbet

Given:

```rb
# typed: true

module X
  class Y
  end
end

module X
  class X
    def y
      X::Y
    end
  end
end
```

Sorbet gives error :

```
editor.rb:6: Unable to resolve constant Y https://srb.help/5002
     6 |      X::Y
```

Why sorbet given error even though X::Y is defined?

[Playground link](https://sorbet.run/#%23%20typed%3A%20true%0A%0Amodule%20X%0A%20%20class%20X%0A%20%20%20%20def%20y%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20X%3A%3AY%0A%20%20%20%20end%0A%20%20end%0Aend%0A%0Amodule%20X%0A%20%20class%20Y%0A%20%20end%0Aend)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because this is how constant lookup works in ruby. Roughly, it tries to resolve the name starting from innermost nesting. Therefore, in a your `X::Y` it resolves `X` to `class X`, which doesn't have `Y`.

Use `::X::Y` instead, to force lookup from top level.

Comment: In other words: if you run the code, you will get the exact same error, and the whole point of a type checker like Sorbet is to give you those errors before you run the code. Or, to put it even more directly: "Why sorbet given error even though X::Y is defined?" – Because it isn't.

Comment: As others have said, this is the behaviour of your code at runtime: `::X::X.new.y #=>  NameError: uninitialized constant X::X::Y`

Comment: I was confused about this behaviour because in Rails app I was working with, it did not result in error when run. Turns out the constant missing did not occur because it is resolved by ActiveSupport.

Thank you for the answer :)